# How can I add a context to ellipse button in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to add a context to an ellipse button but I do not know how I can accomplish it.
So far all what I can do is

`<Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>`

but I do not want a background, I want a text. If someone can help me in here that will help alot..

Here's the code:

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" Height="40" Width="40" Margin="-26,-10,26,10" FontWeight="Bold">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Ellipse/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
    <Button.Content>
        Meat
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

If you can help to me, please copy and past the code with the answer:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Ellipse> 
      <ContentPresenter/>
    </Ellipse>
</Grid>
```